# How to End my Program

Tags: java

I'm writing a program to try and determine if a user-generate number is prime.

**My Code**

[image]

**My Problem**

The program seems to be able to tell if a number is prime or not fine. But I run into an issue when inputing non-prime numbers: it says it is not prime then it is prime, like this:

[image]

I think I could solve this if I was able to end the program in the condition brackets of my if statement. So as soon as we figure out it's not prime, we end the program. Does anyone know how to end the program in my if statement brackets?

Comment: `System.exit(0);` is quick and easy, even if not the best solution.

Comment: Interesting. Tried it an it worked, thanks man. Does there happen to be a reserved word for ending the program, like there is with break and ending a loop?

Comment: @Dunka it's not a "reserved" word - that's something different. It is a system call that exits the program. Just another kind of method

Comment: @Dunka I don't think so. Also, when I said this might not be the best solution, Alex in his answer explains. If you want to use this code in a larger program, the whole thing will exit if the number happens to not be prime. But, quick and easy, System.exit() is the way to go.

Comment: Shortest way is to use `return;` instead of `break;` (preferable over `System.exit(0);` because it doesn't kill your entire VM immediately, if this was in a different method than `main` and you still wanted to do other things)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Takendarkk said in the comment above, you could just call `System.exit(0)` to terminate, but if I were you, I'd just rearrange the flow of the code.

```
boolean isPrime = true;
for( . . . ) {
    if( . . . ) {
        isPrime = false;
        break;
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}

if(isPrime) {
    System.out.println("It is prime!");
} else {
    System.out.println("It is not prime!");
}
```

I guess it doesn't really matter which way you do it. I tend to choose the second way because it makes the process repeatable and useable in other code...

Comment: Thanks for showing me another method. Always cool to see different solutions. Their run times are identical right? Also, why wouldn't I be able to use my code in another project?

Comment: It's probably best to leave a `break;` statement after `isPrime = true;` to stop unnecessary iterations. (Typo alert, change `ipPrime` to `isPrime` in your snippet..)

Comment: @Dunka The run time will be basically the same. Shouldn't be any sort of noticeable difference, especially with the `break;` that Erwin suggested added in. You wouldn't be able to use it in other code because if you stick that in the middle of another project and run it, the `System.exit(0)` call will end the whole class that you're in. Anytime you call that, you terminate the running process. So if this is a subcalculation of something else, you end that something else as well. I try to stay away from `System.exit(0)` when an if statement can do the same thing.

Comment: Would you not want to have `isPrime` setting to false in the loop instead, as the OP had it originally?

Answer (score 3):

`System.exit(0);` will terminate your program.